# Openly available azure service bus topics

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

we are working on an integration with service bus. We don't have an account with azure, so we can't run our own server, but our client does.

For testing purposes, are there any openly available service bus topics I can subscribe to and test our code? the content actually does not matter, we just want to make sure our code can connect and read messages.

If this is not possible, how is the approach for testing our subscription code for azure service bus? Do we need to open a azure account?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do need your own subscription to create and test Service Bus Topics.

To create your free Azure Subscription refer [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/).

Comment: thanks @arunprabhu. do you know if the service bus service is included in the free subscription? it is not specified in the page you posted. thanks.

Comment: You will get $200 free for 30 days. You can create any type of service which falls under $200. So you can create Service Bus under it.